# pcap_lookupdev() is deprecated l. How to resolve it

Tags: ubuntu, tcpdump, libpcap

Since lookupdev has been deprecated in libcap >=1.9, I am facing an error on a code written in v1.8. I have not been able to resolve it.
Suggestion is I use pcap_findalldevs but I am getting an error.

```
int sniffARPPackets(char* gateway, char* gateway_ipp)
```

{

```
strncpy(gtwy, gateway, 17);
strncpy(gateway_ip, gateway_ipp, 15);
int i;
char *dev;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
pcap_t* descr;
const u_char *packet;
struct pcap_pkthdr hdr;
struct ether_header *eptr;
struct bpf_program fp;
bpf_u_int32 maskp;
bpf_u_int32 netp;

dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);

if(dev == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
}

pcap_lookupnet(dev, &netp, &maskp, errbuf);


descr = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, 1,-1, errbuf);
if(descr == NULL) {
    printf("pcap_open_live(): %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
}


if(pcap_compile(descr, &fp, "arp", 0, netp) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error calling pcap_compile\n");
    exit(1);
}


if(pcap_setfilter(descr, &fp) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting filter\n");
    exit(1);
}


pcap_loop(descr, -1, my_callback, NULL);
return 0;
```

}

This is the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it deprecated?

To quote the pcap_lookupdev man page:

```
BUGS
   The pointer returned by pcap_lookupdev() points  to  a  static  buffer;
   subsequent  calls  to  pcap_lookupdev() in the same thread, or calls to
   pcap_lookupdev() in another thread, may overwrite that buffer.

   In WinPcap, this function may return a UTF-16  string  rather  than  an
   ASCII or UTF-8 string.
```

What should you do instead?

To quote the pcap_lookupdev man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
   This  interface  is  obsoleted  by  pcap_findalldevs(3PCAP).  To find a
   default device on which to capture, call pcap_findalldevs() and, if the
   list  it  returns  is not empty, use the first device in the list.  (If
   the list is empty, there are no devices on which capture is  possible.)
```

On every platform except for Windows, `pcap_lookupdev()` calls `pcap_findalldevs()` and returns the first device (unless it's a loopback device), so if `pcap_findalldevs()` isn't working, `pcap_lookupdev()` won't work either. What is the error you're getting with `pcap_findalldevs()`?

Comment: it's deprecated - gcc warning says it `warning: ‘pcap_lookupdev’ is deprecated: use 'pcap_findalldevs' and use the first device`

Answer (score 0):

### Grab the name from the device you want

```
device = all_devs->name;
```

### Example

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *device;
    char error_buffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *handle;
   
    pcap_if_t *all_devs;

    if(pcap_findalldevs(&all_devs, error_buffer) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "error finding devices");
        return 1;
    }

    device = all_devs->name;
    //or loop through all_devs to find the one you want

    if (all_devs == NULL) {
        printf("Error finding devices: %s\n", error_buffer);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Open device for live capture */
    handle = pcap_open_live(
            device,
            BUFSIZ,
            0,
            timeout_limit,
            error_buffer
        );

       ...

      pcap_freealldevs(all_devs);
}
```

### Explanation

Parse through the list and grab the name from the device you want and pass it to pcap_open_live().
The first argument for pcap_openlive() is just a string(char *) indicating the device name.

pcap_findalldevs() returns a list(pointer to the first device) of pcap_if_t(structure for each device). The datastructure has members: next, name,description, addresses, flags.

Each element of the list is of type pcap_if_t, and has the following members:

> **next** if not NULL, a pointer to the next element in the list; NULL for the last element of the list

> **name** ***a pointer to a string giving a name for the device to pass to pcap_open_live()***

> **description** if not NULL, a pointer to a string giving a human-readable description of the device

> **addresses** a pointer to the first element of a list of network addresses for the device, or NULL if the device has no addresses

You can read more [here](https://npcap.com/guide/wpcap/pcap_findalldevs.html)

### Compile your program:

```
gcc capture.c -lpcap
sudo ./a.out
```